# wait until pr2 joint trajectory motion ends

Tags: ros, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to the hardware limitation, the robot did not follow the trajectory as we send via joint_trajectory_action, especially for a torso_controller/joint_trajectory_action of spine joint.
We'd like to wait the program until the pr2 torso movement has finished.
Currently, the robot send back failed status/result after the commanded time period, but the robot still continue to move. Is there a way to know if the robot still moving joint or finished interpolation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10384/wait-until-pr2-joint-trajectory-motion-ends/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you tried your_action_client.wait_for_result() or your_action_client.send_goal_and_wait() (in python)?

---

Originally posted by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) with karma: 152 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-06**:
It sounds like this would work fine if you made your planner plan feasible plans with timeouts which would not be broken in normal operations.

**Comment by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on 2011-06-24**:
I see. So you used your_action_client.get_state()? I also do this to see if the trajectory has completed: print 'arm action state:',actionlib.get_name_of_constant(actionlib.GoalStatus,arm_joint_action_client.get_state()). But you are right, sometimes the robot doesn't complete the trajectory.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-06-24**:
send_goal_and_wait returns with aborted after commanded period has passed, but if the period is too small, say 1 sec for 300mm up of spine joint, the robot continue moving towards the original goal. I'd like to know when the robot reached that point.